# Random rotation function tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
data_augumentation=tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizantal_and_vertical"),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2)
])
```

could someone let me know what does 0.2 represent in RandomRotation function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RandomRotation):

> a float represented as fraction of 2 Pi, or a tuple of size 2 representing lower and upper bound for rotating clockwise and counter-clockwise. A positive values means rotating counter clock-wise, while a negative value means clock-wise. When represented as a single float, this value is used for both the upper and lower bound. For instance, `factor=(-0.2, 0.3)` results in an output rotation by a random amount in the range `[-20% * 2pi, 30% * 2pi]`. `factor=0.2` results in an output rotating by a random amount in the range `[-20% * 2pi, 20% * 2pi]`.

This way, this parameter defines rotation angle range as a fraction of 2 * Pi radians. In your exact case rotation angle range will be: from `-0.4 * pi` to `0.4 * pi`